# How to set Cognito User Pool User DeviceAttributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

GetDevice seems to return DeviceAttributes I can't find an API for setting them. I would like to use them to store the mobile push notification token with the device

```
{
   "Device": { 
      "DeviceAttributes": [ 
         { 
            "Name": "string",
            "Value": "string"
         }
      ],
      "DeviceCreateDate": number,
      "DeviceKey": "string",
      "DeviceLastAuthenticatedDate": number,
      "DeviceLastModifiedDate": number
   }
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GetDevice.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am on the Cognito team. At first we intended DeviceAttributes for a similar use case to the one you are describing, associate the mobile push notification token with the device. However, this has not been released yet and hence there is no API to update the device attributes. I will mention your use case within the team and add a +1 on the feature request.